# Convert SID to String

Tags: c++, winapi, sid

I'm not a C++ developer, so I guess it's just my fault that my program doesn't work.
I want to look up the SID for a windows group and return a readable SID.

```
wchar_t* SpcLookupName(LPCTSTR lpszSystemName, LPCTSTR lpszAccountName) {

PSID         Sid;
DWORD        cbReferencedDomainName, cbSid;
LPTSTR       ReferencedDomainName;
SID_NAME_USE eUse;

cbReferencedDomainName = cbSid = 0;
if (LookupAccountName(lpszSystemName, lpszAccountName, 0, &cbSid,
                    0, &cbReferencedDomainName, &eUse)) {
    SetLastError(ERROR_NONE_MAPPED);
    return 0;
}

if (GetLastError(  ) != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) return 0;

if (!(Sid = (PSID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cbSid))) return 0;

ReferencedDomainName = (LPTSTR)LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, cbReferencedDomainName);

if (!ReferencedDomainName) {
    LocalFree(Sid);
    return 0;
}

if (!LookupAccountName(lpszSystemName, lpszAccountName, Sid, &cbSid,
                     ReferencedDomainName, &cbReferencedDomainName, &eUse)) {
    LocalFree(ReferencedDomainName);
    LocalFree(Sid);
    return 0;
}

wchar_t* psz;

// Loading ConvertSidToStringSid
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *tConvertSidToStringSid)(PSID,wchar_t*);

tConvertSidToStringSid pConvertSidToStringSid=0;

HINSTANCE handle = ::LoadLibrary("Advapi32.dll");

pConvertSidToStringSid = (tConvertSidToStringSid) ::GetProcAddress(handle, "ConvertSidToStringSidA");

if(pConvertSidToStringSid(Sid, psz)){                               
    return psz;
}
}
```

My problem is that the function returns only some strange characters and not the SID, why?

Comment: How are you doing the print? - the function returns a pointer to a string, I can't see a print statement?

Comment: I tested it with a message box, but it's not in the code right now.

Comment: Really, wouldn't this be easier in something like PowerShell or .net or Python where it's wrapped up for you. Hacking together tools like this in C++ is painful, especially if you aren't really fluent in C++. There's probably even an res kit console app that will do this for you anyway!

Comment: I want to use it as Library in Java. Is is possible to use .net in Java?

Comment: what about this: http://www.koders.com/java/fid775B8ABD368773353F72940E2A4819FE5BAD1FE0.aspx?s=234 C++ seems overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of obvious things wrong with your code...

1) the prototype for `ConvertSidToStringSid()` is `BOOL ConvertSidToStringSid(PSID Sid, LPTSTR *StringSid)`; which means that your typedef should be `typedef BOOL (WINAPI *tConvertSidToStringSid)(PSID,LPTSTR *);`

2) you are looking up the ANSI version and passing a wchar_t *... You should either look up the wide character version `ConvertSidToStringSid()` or, a better solution, IMHO, look up `ConvertSidToStringSid` and use a `TCHAR *` rather than a `wchar_t *` as this will work no matter what your unicode compile settings are, and it matches the typedef.

3) finally due to the broken typedef you're being allowed to pass the wrong data type to the function. It wants a `LPTSTR *` and you're passing it a `LPTSTR` (well, actually you're passing a `wchar_t *`... The `LPTSTR` is in fact the unicode aware type that maps to a `wchar_t *` if you're using wide characters but the function that you are calling wants a pointer to that pointer and not the pointer itself.

So, the fixed code is:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *tConvertSidToStringSid)(PSID,LPTSTR*);

tConvertSidToStringSid pConvertSidToStringSid=0;

HINSTANCE handle = ::LoadLibrary("Advapi32.dll");



pConvertSidToStringSid = (tConvertSidToStringSid) ::GetProcAddress(handle, #ConvertSidToStringSid);

if(pConvertSidToStringSid(Sid, &psz)){                               
    return psz;
}
```

Note the change to the typedef, the change to the GetProcAddress call (where we use the # to stringize the function name (which will either be ConvertSidToStringSidA or ConvertSidToStringSidW depending on your unicode settings) and the change to pass the address of psz rather than the pointer itself.

And now your only problem is that you're potentially leaking that psz unless you are making sure you free it in the caller with a call to `LocalFree()`.

Note that depending on the calling code, you might want to convert the typedef into `wchar_t **` rather than `LPTSTR *` and then use the ConvertSidToStringSidW version to force the result to always be a wide character string.

Comment: I tried it that way, but  now i get these two messages:   "stray '#' in program"   and    "'ConvertSidToStringSid' was not declared in this scope".

Comment: Ok, I never compiled it and couldn't be bothered to cruft up another macro for the name in text form. Just use the wchar_t version and ConvertSidToStringSidW BUT make sure you fix the typedef and the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `pConvertSidToStringSid(Sid, psz)` call is not successful and `SpcLookupName()` return value is undefined because you don't return anything.

And why are you mixing `ConvertSidToStringSidA` with wchar_t? It would be better to use `ConvertSidToStringSid` from `Sddl.h` directly:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <Sddl.h>
```

You should also return `LPTSTR` from your function instead of `wchar_t *`

Comment: pConvertSidToStringSid(Sid, psz) is successful. I tested it with a message box, it's just not in the code I pasted here.

Answer (score 0):

You use `ConvertSidToStringSidA` which will return ANSI string, at the same time you are expecting `wchar_t*`. Try to use `ConvertSidToStringSidW` instead. Or just include `Sddl.h` and use `ConvertSidToStringSid`.

Comment: I tried it with ConvertSidToStringSidW before and it didn't worked. So ConvertSidToStringSidA was just another try, sorry for mixing it up here.

I included ssdl.h, but if i call "ConvertSidToStringSid" the compiler says "'ConvertSidToStringSid' was not declared in this scope".

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the ANSI version of the function when you want the Unicode version `"ConvertSidToStringSidW"`.

Also you have a small memory leak as you aren't alway freeing `Sid`.